# Resolving the issue: Illegal characters in path

Tags: java, xml, filepath

I am developing an application that takes an XML file and an attachment to be sent to the following path. This path is for a fax appliance.

I keep getting this error message:

> Problem processing drop file "\co1-aux01prd01.tampa.healthe\Fax_Drop\Outbox\FaxDropSample1.xml": Illegal characters in path.

The XML file and the attachment are both being created but not processed.

```
public class TestSender {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String outBox = "\\\\faxaux\\Fax_Drop\\Outbox";
        String filename = "FaxDrop" + ".xml";
        String filepath = outBox + "\\" + filename;
        Writer writer = null;

        try {
            BufferedImage image;
            URL url = new URL("http://colsolgrp.com/phone/jpg/fax8.jpg");
            image = ImageIO.read(url);
            //File newImage = new File("\\\\faxaux\\Fax_Drop\\Outbox\\AttachmentFolder\\attachment.jpg");
            File newImage = new File("\\\\faxaux\\Fax_Drop\\Outbox\\FaxDrop\\FaxDropImage.jpg");
            newImage.mkdirs();
            newImage.createNewFile();
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",newImage);
            System.out.println("File has been written");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not create file");
        }

        try {
            File f = new File(filepath);
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
            writer = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
            // Create XML file here
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                writer.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                // Do nothing.
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Success");
```

Comment: @LutzHorn: It's common in Windows file shares. But I suspect Java may not handle it...

Comment: Please can you post some code showing how you are using this path in Java?

Comment: We might need to see what code you're using trying to write that file. It might not support UNC paths.

Comment: @DarthJDG I posted the code please take a look

Comment: @Duncan I posted the code please take a look

Comment: That code did not generate the error message above (the paths are different, for a start). Are you sure you still see an error? Can you correct the error to match the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
URI u = new URI(URLEncoder.encode("\\co1-aux01prd01.tampa.healthe\Fax_Drop\Outbox\FaxDropSample1.xml"));
```